# What's wrong in this "mergeSort"?

Tags: java, sorting, mergesort

There's a *mergeSort* code that I copied at class lesson, can you help me to find the errors?

When I run the main that use `mergeSort` the program enters in an infinite loop but doesn't display any error. I tried to run in debug mode but I am not very expert and I don't find what's wrong. However I think that the error is in `mergeSort(int[] v, int inf, int sup)` recursion.

```
public class CopyOfSortMethods {

private static void merge(int[] v, int inf, int med, int sup) {
    int aux[] = new int[v.length];
    int i = inf;
    int j = med + 1;
    int k = inf;

    while ((i <= med) && (j <= sup)) {
        if (v[i] < v[j]) {
            aux[k] = v[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        } else {
            aux[k] = v[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }
    while (i <= med) {
        aux[k] = v[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while (j <= sup) {
        aux[k] = v[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= sup; i++) {
        v[i] = aux[i];
    }
}

public static void mergeSort(int[] v, int inf, int sup) {
    int med;

    while (inf < sup){
        med = (inf + sup)/2;
        mergeSort(v, inf, med);
        mergeSort(v, med + 1, sup);
        merge(v, inf, med, sup);
    }
}

public static void mergeSort(int[] v) {
    if(v!=null) {
        mergeSort(v, 0, v.length - 1);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: What do you see when you step through your code in a debugger?  What is the simplest example which demonstrates your problem?

Comment: That's because in Java variables are passed by value, not by refs. So inf and sup stayed the same in the mergeSort function.

Comment: @maverik what do you mean?

Comment: When i run in debug mode i notice that when the mergeSort while should ends, it continue to run from the second recursion.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, I mean while (inf < sup) loop never ends because I can't find any place where inf and/or sup are changed.

Comment: @maverik i understand for variables passage but, where you say is the error?

Comment: @maverik then the problem is not because the variables are passed by value, the problem is that the condition must be an `if` and not a `while`...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, yep, looks like you're right. I'm not concentrated enough, unfortunately :(

Comment: ok...i'll try to find a solution, thank you :)

Comment: @93zone, thanks to Luiggi Mendoza. You should probably try to use if instead of while.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza changing "while" with "if" it doesn't work right...trying to sort this int array {4,3,1,5,0} it return {0,0,0,0,5}

Comment: @93zone making the change makes your code at least finish. Now then, **debug it** and find the new errors. Hint: check the `for` at the bottom of your `merge` method.

Comment: @93zone : The algorithm requires it to be a 'while' condition. It's as maverik said. inf and sup are never updated.

Comment: @sanjeevmk no it doesn't require that, note that the recursive call to the method already handles the loop. Have you ever implemented a merge sort?

Comment: @sanjeevmk i think that LuiggiMendoza is right because now at least the machine doesn't enter in infinite loop.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i'm running in debug mode and i noticed that the error(s) are in merge method...i'm trying to find them...thank you.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza sorry for the trouble but at the moment when the array {4,3,1,5,0} is correctly sorted until the penultimate digit {1,3,4,5,0} in "merge" last "for cicle" the array aux is copied into v but at this moment, aux conains [0,0,0,0,5}

Comment: @93zone the problem is that in your aux array you're setting data from `[inf]` to `[sup]` and `inf` doesn't start on 0. That's why I told you to check the `for` at the bottom of the method.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ahahah i found the error immediately after i posted the comment...thank you so much (i'm new in this forum, how can i add to you reputation points? )

Comment: I should post an answer and you would accept it. I'll post an answer after having my lunch :). By the way, this site is not a forum, it is a Question and Answer site. Read more in the [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Comment: ok, i signed up this site today...thank you...have a good lunch :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems in your merge sort (based in the comments):

1. In `mergeSort` method, you're recursively calling the `mergeSort` inside a `while` loop and never changing the values of `inf` and `sup`. Change this for an `if` instead.

   ```
    if (inf < sup) {
        //code goes here...
    }
   ```
2. In your `merge` sort, at the bottom of the method body, you're moving the items **all** the items from `aux` array to `v` array. You should only move the elements between `inf` and `sup`:

   ```
   //for (i = 0; i <= sup; i++) {
   for (i = inf; i <= sup; i++) {
       //code goes here...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

As Maverik points out, the issue is the `while` loop in `mergeSort()`.

`inf` and `sup` are never modified, so `inf` is always less than `sup`. The loop never terminates.